# Nutch+Solr: How do you index a PDF embedded in HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, solr, nutch, apache-tika

I am using Nutch+Solr to index my website for an internal search bar. The website has many HTML pages with embedded PDFs, and I want the text from the PDFs to show up in searches. Indexing the text in the HTML works fine, and I can index the PDFs separately, but I want a single Solr document with the text from the HTML and its embedded PDF together. Is there a way to do this?

This is how the PDFs are embedded:

```
<object data="path/to/document.pdf#view=FitH" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="700">
</object>
```

I'm wondering if the solution might have something to do with Tika's EmbeddedDocumentExtractor. However, I'm at a loss for how to change Tika's configuration within Nutch or Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Tika treats the PDF file as a link, the EmbeddedDocumentExtractor is used for content in-lined via [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Embedding the PDF would require to modify Tika's HtmlHandler or Nutch's parse-tika plugin. Note that Nutch does not yet handle links in `<object>` elements, to be addressed in [NUTCH-2880](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2880).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'll replace the <object> with an <iframe> so that Nutch can crawl the PDF. I guess the HTML and PDF will end up in two different Solr documents, but I'm thinking of a workaround in which the UI returns a link to the HTML page when there's a search hit in the PDF.